# Nginx ingress controller websocket support

Tags: nginx, websocket, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Recently I've been working on a toy app using Kubernetes. Part of the app is a web server that needs to support WebSockets. Currently, I'm using port-forwarding to access the web server and everything works just fine.

I'd like to switch to using an Ingress and IngressController to avoid using the port forwarding.

Here is my `Ingress` config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /app
        backend:
          serviceName: web-svc
          servicePort: 3030
      - path: /ws
        backend:
          serviceName: web-svc
          servicePort: 3030
```

Now accessing the app through `$(minikube ip)/app` works just fine, but the WebSocket requests all fail because nginx is returning a 200 and not a 101.

I've tried adding the `nginx.org/websocket-services` annotation but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation?

Cheers

Comment: According to https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/miscellaneous/#websockets "Support for websockets is provided by NGINX out of the box. No special configuration required." But I can't get it to work.

Also it is easy to get confused due to the two nginx controllers. See https://www.nginx.com/blog/wait-which-nginx-ingress-controller-kubernetes-am-i-using/

Comment: the quotes around the timeouts seem to be important with newer k8s versions

Answer (score 20):

From looking at the [nginx ingress controller docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#configuration-snippet) and the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) you probably need something like this as an annotation on your Kubernetes `Ingress`:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";
   proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
```

Note that once you add that annotation all of your `Ingress` rules will have that snippet in the `location` block in your nginx configs. So if you want to ignore it for other rules you will have to create a separate Kubernetes `Ingress`.

EDIT:

As per the [gist](https://gist.github.com/jsdevtom/7045c03c021ce46b08cb3f41db0d76da#file-ingress-service-yaml) and the [Nginx ingress docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/miscellaneous/#websockets) , it seems like this annotation fixed the problem:

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: 3600
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: 3600
```

Comment: I'm still fighting. I will comment back here when I understand the problem

Comment: Ok I did it. I have described the working configuration in this gist: https://gist.github.com/jsdevtom/7045c03c021ce46b08cb3f41db0d76da#file-ingress-service-yaml

Comment: @Tom can you describe what's the important part? I seem to be missing it from your gist.

Comment: I agree . @tom in your snippet I couldn't find nginx-ingress configuration snippet as to how did that work What you have is the ingress rule and not ingress controller annotation.

Comment: Edited the question, seems like it was the timeout annotations

Answer (score 14):

Theese worked for me.

It seems they added support via annotation ([example in docs](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/main/examples/ingress-resources/websocket)):

```
nginx.org/websocket-services: "service1[,service2,...]"
```

I tested my connection with [telsocket](https://github.com/lafikl/telsocket), small tool to connect to a WS/WSS socket.

There are all sorts of different clients, this might also help finding the culprit with the connection.

**Important to note:** two nginx ingress controllers are available, more info [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/guide-to-choosing-ingress-controller-part-4-nginx-ingress-controller-options).

This answer is limited to the nginxinc version, that is different that used in the question, the accepted answer is the only solution as of right now.

Comment: supported since which version ?

Comment: Based on git history of the linked file, since v1.12.1. You can check the commit [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/commit/cad5d7ded7927d1994bfec43e2c06183295c23f4#diff-cc5dca25dead8470544fcfe6a9297e82de1b3897c092fb519e2019dd4c066d6e) .

Comment: My bad, it is included since 2016, so the first tag contained this code was: v0.3.

Comment: Does this only work with the NGINX Inc controller?

Comment: Yes, unfortonutely it is limited to the nginxinc version.

Comment: Thank you, works well with v3.2.1, installed from official chart 0.18.1.

Answer (score 2):

for people who are using classic ELB using nginx ingress controller . websocket is not supported. don't spend more time .
https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/features/

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I've used (please check the annotations area):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: tornado-socket
 annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippets: |
   location / {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
spec:....
```

It seems that this annotations are required for the free version of Ingress-NgInx.
Full article: https://www.civo.com/learn/using-websockets-with-ingress-controller

Comment: I've tried, it doesn't work for v3.2.1, installed from official chart 0.18.1. But works with "nginx.org/websocket-services: name-of-your-svc"