# What version of the Kubernetes NGINX Ingress supports websockets?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, websocket

I ran across [an article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) that says that the NGINX Ingress supports websockets starting at version 1.3.  But [this changelog](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/Changelog.md) mentions websocket documentation back at version 0.9.

I'm running with NGINX Ingress at version 0.23.0 and I cannot get the websocket client connection to work.  It fails because the Connection header is `keep-alive` instead of `upgrade`.  It looks like the ingress is changing it, because the connection works if I bypass the ingress and go directly to the Kubernetes service.  Before I go much further, it would be good to know if this is hopeless with the version of NGINX that I currently have running.

Comment: ingress-nginx 0.23.0 packages nginx 1.15.9, so nginx itself supports websockets. I'm not sure you can get Upgrade working without a special config but I believe a  `path` to a dedicated ws server should work - https://gist.github.com/jsdevtom/7045c03c021ce46b08cb3f41db0d76da#file-ingress-service-yaml

Comment: @cbarlock Was the above info helpful?

Comment: Thank you Matt.  I was not aware of the packaging & versioning you mention above.  I had found that link you referenced and think I have my Ingress YAML definitions set up correctly.  I'm writing in Go using the gorilla/websocket package.  I see the request come in, but gorilla rejects it because the Connection HTTP header is set to `keep-alive` instead of `upgrade`.  Can you say any more about this "special config"?

Comment: The NGINX Ingress doc says you need to add an annotation for those services that support websockets.  I added:

`nginx.org/websocket-services: tcs-bvt-eprouter-websocket`

And have a service with the name above.  I would expect that the Ingress would say "oh, a websocket.  It needs the Connection header to be `upgrade`, but that seems not to be happening.

Comment: Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: I do not have it working yet.

Comment: Have you seen [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52883653/nginx-ingress-controller-websocket-support)? Looks like the same problem you are experiencing right now.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Our Helm charts were explicitly setting the Ingress annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/connection-proxy-header` to `keep-alive`. Removed that and all is well.