# K8s socket.io and websocket ingress configuration

Tags: node.js, sockets, kubernetes, websocket, nginx-ingress

I have a problem with my ingress, basically in my k8s cluster there are two chat and notification microservices, these are two microservices which, in addition to exposing APIs, expose a web socekt with socket.io and a normal websocket.

Chat

```
const {Server} = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server); 

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('New connection started', socket.id);
});
```

Notification

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({server});

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    console.log('Client connected', ws);
});
```

Each microservice is deployed with associated service on my k8s cluster.

But now I can't establish socket and web-socket connections through my ingress, here is my config:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 64m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '3600'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '3600'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '3600'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: demo.local.home
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /ct(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ct-svc
                port:
                  number: 8110
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ct-svc
                port:
                  number: 8210
          - path: /nt(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ntf-svc
                port:
                  number: 8111
          - path: /demo
                    pathType: Prefix
                    backend:
                      service:
                        name: dm-svc
                        port:
                          number: 8290
```

The services respond correctly via REST API, but I can't connect to the socket.io and web-socket, would you have any advice to make my configuration work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52883653/5319180 Have you looked at this? Nginx ingress requires some additional annotations to allow it to handle websockets

Comment: I solve the problem for the websocket, but stil cannot connect to my socket.io server, i updated my ingress config

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve the problem, here is the final configuration:

```
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 64m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '3600'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '3600'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '3600'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: demo.local.home
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /ct(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ct-svc
                port:
                  number: 8110
          - path: /nt(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ntf-svc
                port:
                  number: 8111
          - path: /demo
                    pathType: Prefix
                    backend:
                      service:
                        name: dm-svc
                        port:
                          number: 8290
```

with:

- socket.io host: http://demo.local.home/ct/
- websocket host: ws://demo.local.home/nt/

Comment: What was exactly the problem?